# Camel: how to check response http response

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am pretty new with Camel. I have been trying to submit a data (Json from a file) to a webservice. This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // create CamelContext
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        // add our route to the CamelContext
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
                    .marshal()
                    .string()
                    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
                    .to("http://www.a-service.com");
            }
        });

        // start the route and let it do its work
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // stop the CamelContext
        context.stop();
    }
```

Then the webservice will response with Json which can be
   {result:OK}
 or 
   {result:FAIL}

Now, if a response has responseCode as 200, Camel will consider as success.

My question is, how can I have a validating process for responsed JSon  so that if it is FAIL, Camel should not consider as success?

**Solution** Credit @Namphibian:

By adding processor and the end. This code has been tested:

```
    from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
        .marshal()
        .string("UTF-8")
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
    .to("http://monrif-test.userspike.com/monrif/rss/monrif_-all-global")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Message in = exchange.getIn();
                String msg = in.getBody(String.class);
                System.out.println("Response: " + msg);
                if(msg.contains("OK")){
                    // go to party
                }else{
                    throw new Exception("test exception");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two broad strategies you can use to achieve this.

**Processor Based:**

Add a processor to the end of the route. In this processor do the check if the webservice then responds with a true or false value.

A processor would look something like this:

```
    package com.example;

    import java.util.Map;

    import org.apache.camel.Body;
    import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
    import org.apache.camel.Handler;
    import org.apache.camel.Headers;
    import org.apache.camel.Message;

    public class GeneralProcessor {
        @Handler

        public void PrepapreErrorImportReport
        (

                @Headers Map hdr
                , Exchange exch
        )
        {

            //todo: Get the message as a string;

            Message in = exch.getIn();
            String msg = (String)in.getBody();
            // Now check if body contains failed or ok.
            if(msg.contains("OK")){
                //todo: go party the message was OK
            }
            else{
               //todo: Oh Oh! Houston we have a problem
            }


        }

    }
```

You can then modify your route to use this processor.

**The Simple Expression Language**

This is one way the other way is to use the simple expression language. See the example below on how to use this.

```
 from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
                .marshal()
                .string()
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
                .to("http://www.a-service.com")
                .choice()
                .when(simple("${body} contains 'OK'")).to("activemq:okqueue")
                .otherwise().to("activemq:queue:other");
```

Notice the `simple("${body} contains 'OK'")` piece of code. That is the power of simple.

Both approaches have uses.

Comment: many thanks for the long answer. I have a question. At "//todo: Oh Oh! Houston we have a problem" , should I just throw an exception or there is better way ?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Do u want to throw exception or just report a failure back to caller. Really depends on what you want.

Comment: OK. For now, I just want it be fail. So, I guess the exception throwing is enough. Thanks again.

Comment: I would like to modify your answer a bit so that newbie can use it easier.

Comment: I have one more question. If I want to backup file to different folders (ex outbox_sucess and outbox_fail) depended on result, how can I dot that ?  Because from your second solution, the body has been changed to be the http response, not the original body of the file in 'inbox'.

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen see this link http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html. It is a essential concept to understand. The in message to the web service is the file. The response is the out message that becomes the in message for the choice. Essentially as soon as you write to a out message it destroys the in message. Read the link it will explain it.

Comment: just checked the docs for ToD and no mention at all of the possibility of the http call failing

Answer (score 2):

In the `Process` method , you can use below method and it will work

```
LOGGER.info("Response code " + message.getHeader(exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class));
```

Comment: This is the correct way of checking the HTTP status code. However the question mentions that the result of the HTTP call will be a JSON string like {result:OK} or {result:FAIL} which is not related to the HTTP status code at all.